# How to get rid of display corruption during horizontal scroll in WPF4 DataGrid with grouping?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to create a datagrid with grouping and I'm getting display corruption (blank areas) during horizontal scrolling. The issue appears **only** when there is a GroupStyle.ContainerStyle defined. The datagrid should contain 200 rows or more to reproduce the problem.

**UPDATE2:**
[Related Microsoft Connect feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/677198/render-glitches-in-wpf4-datagrid-with-disabled-virtualization).

**UPDATE:**
Microsoft guy at [social.msdn.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cf47f2e9-e488-42f0-9407-5a668d5c086f/) pointed out that adding grouping turns off datagrid virtualization. Possibly that's the root of the problem. I removed grouping from my sample and set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` to `false` and got exactly the same kind of corruption.

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=cvsGoods}}"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <ItemsPresenter  />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

After several horizontal scrolls to the right and back to the left blank areas appear on the left side. I tried it on WinXP and Win7.

The question is: how to get rid of that bug? Is there any workaround? Any suggestions?

Screenshot illustrating the problem:

[image: Display corruption]

Comment: Any luck with this?  I am having a very similar issue with FrozenColumns

Comment: @AlanR No, no luck at all. I had to fall back to WinForms. But MS knows about it so I hope it will be fixed in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

We once faced the same issue (but not the same cause) i.e. the datagrid will have blank areas just before the first column of some of the rows. The way we solved (a hack) it at that time was by disabling the rowheader (don't know how it solved the problem but did figure out that the blank areas were actually rowheaders).

We disabled (correct word would be made it size-zero) the rowheader by setting the width to zero, something like the code below:

```
<wpftk:DataGrid>
...
...
<wpftk:DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style  TargetType="wpftk:DataGridRowHeader" >
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</wpftk:DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
...
...
</wpftk:DataGrid>
```

Let me know if it works in your case.

One more thing we noticed that if we either disable the virtualization or rowheaderstyle, it would solve our problem. We went for disabling the rowheader as we didn't need it.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. I tried also disabling virtualization but it doesn't help too. But I'll try to dig in that direction. Interesting thing: I can't reproduce it at home. Might be a graphic driver-related issue. Anyway, as a quick fix I used two datagrids with vertical scroll syncronization. Crude, but works...

Comment: I would say if you can't produce it at hope it is probably a graphic driver issue. Although you could double check that you have the same service packs and hotfixes installed.

Comment: @MattWest, sorry for delayed response. In fact I was able to reproduce it at home. (I just needed to increase number of rows.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, but when scrolling is completed just call InvalidateVisual() on the control.

Also, since you say it's with approximately 200 rows, we've encountered similar responsiveness issues with high load. We were able to work around it by updating the UI from the background thread. You can read more on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx).

Comment: I tried calling `InvalidateVisual()` on my `DataGrid` control in `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` handler. Unfortunately, no effect. Also, there are no responsiveness issues, everything works smooth enough, but, alas, with rendering artifacts. 8(

Answer (score 1):

I think your template for groupstyle is causing some clipping, I tried loading up 1000 rows and it worked fine. One more catch here is try hosting the header inside a container, In the below sample I used a TreeViewItem,

```
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                                        <TreeViewItem.Header>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                        </TreeViewItem.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </TreeViewItem>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

Let me know if this helps.

-Fahad

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. In fact, even if I don't define anything and just write: `<DataGrid.GroupStyle><GroupStyle></GroupStyle></DataGrid.GroupStyle>` I still get the corruption.

Comment: Can you post your full sample in some pastebin or any online code viewer? let me check on that.

Comment: OK, I'll publish it somewhere. 
BTW, it seems I've located the source of the problem: grouping switches off the datagrid virtualization (see update in the question)

Comment: I dont think turning off virtualization would cause this issue, because turning off means it would load all the UIElements in memory and do Measure & arrange. I did a quick check with my random sample, it does work again. May be there is some other setting that you are using.

Comment: @Fahad, I just created an empty WPF project in VS2010, added a `CollectionViewSource` and `DataGrid` to main window, populated the `CollectionViewSource` in `Window_Loaded` handler and that's all. Could you suggest a site to upload the code? I tried with sourceforge and codeplex but both just gave me errors and I couldn't deploy...

Comment: I've published an example to https://wpf4datagridiss.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/wpf4datagridiss/

Comment: thanks, I did a quick check and I'm able to reproduce the issue when the virtualization is turned off, I think this is the reason why it is occuring when you use grouping. So that makes sense, because the item in the container is not refreshed / invalidated when the item is scrolled back. Also, clipping seems to be completely broken if the item is not virtualized, this may be happening because of the assumption that the text won't be beyond the view port size. One rude fix is to Invalidate the grid whenever the scroll offset is changed,

    grid.InvalidateArrange()

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't help me. I added a `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event handler which calls `InvalidateArrange()` method of my grid and I still got the corruption. (I also tried IvalidateVisual previosly (on Ben K.'s advice -- see the other answer) and it didn't help either.)